# How can I validate GET controller params in CakePHP 2?

Tags: validation, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

Given this on the model:

```
public $validate = [
    'amount' => array(
        'rule' => array('comparison', '>=', 0),
        'message' => 'You must buy over 0 of this item!'
    )
];
```

How can I validate param #2 of the below?

`public function buy(int $item, int $amount) {`

Validation seems to be built only for POST, which I'd like to opt out of here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First things first, modifying the database with `GET` requests is an anti-pattern for many different reasons. Even if you assume a friendly user agent (which you never should!), browsers can behave quirky and do unexpected stuff like for example sending `GET` request multiple times (that is perfectly valid as `GET` is not ment to modify data), which they usually won't for `POST/PUT/DELETE`.

I would strongly suggest to change your endpoint to handle `POST` requests instead.

That being said, you can generally validate whatever you want, the validation mechanisms first and foremost just validate data, they don't know or care where it stems from. You can hand over whatever data you want to your model, and let it validate it:

```php
$data = array(
    'item' => $item,
    'amount' => $amount,
);
$this->ModelName->set($data);

if ($this->ModelName->validates()) {
    // data is valid
} else {
    // data is invalid
    $errors = $this->ModelName->validationErrors;
}
```

Moreover you can use CakePHP's validation methods completely manually too:

```php
App::uses('Utility', 'Validation');

$isValid = Validation::comparison($amount, '>' 0);
```

This example of course doesn't make too much sense, given that `$isValid = $amount > 0` would do the same, however it should just show that you can validate anything everywhere without models being involved.

See also

- **[Cookbook > Models > Data Validation > Validating Data from the Controller](https://book.cakephp.org/2/en/models/data-validation/validating-data-from-the-controller.html)**
- **[Cookbook > Models > Data Validation > Core Validation Rules](https://book.cakephp.org/2/en/models/data-validation.html#core-validation-rules)**

Comment: @VaelVictus Something normal would for example be preflight requests for CORS, however that would be an `OPTIONS` request of course, but if you don't handle them in your app, you'll have a problem in your `GET` endpoints. A better example might for example be Firefox, where it aborts `GET` requests if it cannot find charset information in the first x bytes of the response, and then sends the same request again where it will assume a specific charset. CSRF is also something to keep in mind, `GET` endpoints usually aren't protected against that, so an attacker could easily exploit that.